# Create a multi dimensional array every 3 elements

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the following array:

```
Array {
    [0] => text1
    [1] => text2
    [3] => text3
    [4] => text4
    ...
    [200] => text200
}
```

How can I create a foreach loop that will divide the above array to create a sub array for every 3 elements?

```
Array {
    [0] => Array {
                [0] => text1
                [1] => text2
                [2] => text3 
    }
    [1] => Array {
                [0] => text4
                [1] => text5
                [2] => text6
    }   
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can [use](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)  a build in function , `array_chunk()`

```
array_chunk($input_array, 3)
```